# I need to get values in between {{ }} in a object in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get the values in between `{{ }}` from "htmlPart".
But I need to make that work to a generic function, every time I read a {{ string }} I need to get the string and include in a list.

The object:

```
dict = {
    "variaveis": "usuario, password", 
    "htmlPart": "Hi {{ usuario }}, your password is: {{ password }}"
}
```

I`m learning python, so I need a little help with that.

Comment: what have you tried? for example, you could iterate over the dict with `.items()` like `for key, value in my_dict.items()`

Comment: Use a regular expression `{{(.*?)}}`

Comment: To elaborate on the above: `import re` then you can use `re.findAll` with `re.findall(r'{{\s+(.*?)\s+}}', d['htmlPart'])`

Comment: You don't need a dictionary if you had a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
dict = { "variaveis": "usuario, password", "htmlPart": "Hi {{ usuario }}, your password is: {{ password }}" }
user_greeting = dict["htmlPart"].split(",")[0] # "Hi {{ usuario }}"
user = re.findall(r'\w+', user_greeting)[1] # usario

print(user)
```

output: Usario

Then to add to a list:

```
ex_li = []
ex_li.append(user)
```

You may want to use a list comprehension instead.